# leave row event gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can I get the row leave event of a GridView?

Answer (score 0):

The `GridView` does not have a `row leave` event.

See the list of existing events [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_events.aspx).